# Shutdown BlueCove stack programmatically

Tags: java

Is there any way to shutdown the BlueCove stack, in my application user can able to start, stop and restart the bluetooth server whenever they wish, for that I can able to start the server, listen for connection, accept message from the client. But when I try to stop and restart the BlueCove, I'm gettting BluetoothStateException, instead I've to restart the application itself.

For shutting down I used,

```
BlueCoveImpl.shutdown();
```

and another thing

```
BlueCoveImpl blueCoveImpl = BlueCoveImpl.instance();
blueCoveImpl.setBluetoothStack(null);
```

but both not worked for me.

Any Ideas to do this.

EDIT: When I close the whole application it displays

> BlueCove stack shutdown completed

in the Console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I start the Bluetooth server, I set it to be visible in search mode using,

```
LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
```

and to stop the server I just added the following code,

```
local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.NOT_DISCOVERABLE);
```

and this one solved my problem.

Comment: While this does turn off Bluetooth communication, it does not completely shutdown the bluetooth stack. I'm not sure if this is a bad alternative, but I would assume that doing this would not release the resources being used by the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth Stack remains live until you shut it down manually or until it shuts down on program exit.

A manual shutdown is called using the following from `com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl`:

```
BlueCoveImpl.shutdown();
```

[From the docs](http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/com/intel/bluetooth/BlueCoveImpl.html#shutdown()):

> public static void shutdown()
>
> Shutdown all BluetoothStacks interfaces initialized by BlueCove

You can also use:

> public static void shutdownThreadBluetoothStack()
>
> Shutdown BluetoothStack assigned for current Thread and clear configuration properties for this thread

---

I can confirm this is doing the same work as what is automatically done at the end of the program... When first initializing using something like `LocalDevice.getLocalDevice()`, you'll see the console print out:

> BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT on winsock

or something similar. At termination, the console prints:

> BlueCove stack shutdown completed

However, if you call `shutdown()` before the program ends, "BlueCove stack shutdown completed" will not print. In addition, calling again `LocalDevice.getLocalDevice()` will bring up the first message once more.